# Order form required as part of course module

Tags: php, javascript, forms

Im currently enrolled in a diploma of it(websites)

As per course requirements i am expected to create a page with a list of products. And then create an order form with following requirements

```
      o Facility for customers to fill out an order form. You must include code to validate the fields of the order form. This code must include:
            + Variables and arrays
            + Functions which use arguments
            + String functions
            + Conditionals (if/else statements)
```

Im guessing they are talking about the combination of php forms and javascript to submit the information

The course is a online course however the material isnt really helping at all. I work as a technical trainee at a music place. The course is sposed to be making up for my lack of training to this stage as i have been learning on the job implementing predeveloped java plugins and modifiying them into my own html/css designs. Kinda sucks cause i have no trainer....

I know a fair ammount about server mechanics and general css/html.

I have no background in PHP, JAVA or mysql in terms of building from scratch.

I'm wondering if anybody on these boards can recommend some good books or post in a bit of code to head me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am lucky that my local library has many books on PHP and MYSQL.

I read `PHP 6 and MySQL 6 bible / Steve Suehring, Tim Converse, Joyce Park` and found it very useful. I don't know how much it would cost to actually buy but there were many other books that looked comparable.

I would also check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp as they have quite a bit of useful information packed into a small tutorial